# Conversion from nvarchar to time format failing?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, type-conversion

I'm trying to convert from nvarchar to time but I get a conversion from nvarchar to date and/or time failed exception.
This is my stored procedure:

```
USE [groep2_festivals]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[AddBandFestival]    Script Date: 15-05-13 2:52:38 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Robbie Vercammen
-- Create date: 2013-05-14
-- Description: Inserts a new record into the bandsperfestival table
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddBandFestival]
    (
    @festId int,
    @bandId int,
    @podId int,
    @date nvarchar,
    @hour nvarchar
    )
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO bandsperfestival
    (fest_id, band_id, pod_id, datum, uur)
    VALUES (@festId, @bandId, @podId, @date, CONVERT(time, @hour, 108))
END
```

The convert function should do the trick, but it doesn't.
The debugger says that this string was given to the stored procedure: "23:01:00"
And according to this page: http://networking.ringofsaturn.com/SQL/howtoformatdatetime.php and msdn 108 should be the correct style for this conversion, right?

EDIT: extra info
the datum `column` is of type `date` and `uur` is of type `time`

Comment: Are you sure its not whining about `@date` ? What is its value?

Comment: No it's not date, I've used the same method for other stored procedures. The value is 2013-07-01

Comment: Well, I can convert both these values. Is there a trigger or such?

Comment: Nope, no triggers or anything. Very weird

Comment: Does it work if executed manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the size;

```
@date nvarchar,
@hour nvarchar
```

So they truncate to a single character that cannot be converted, so change to `@hour(8)`

Comment: Sorry for the late response... That was exactly what went wrong.
I initially had these sizes but got lost in the many attempts. Thanks!

Comment: @gbn I guess that what you get for trying to answer newbish questions like this one, always expect the easiest of mistakes first :)

Answer (score 0):

It accepts literal translation;

```
Declare @time as time
SET @time = '23:00:01'
SELECT @time
```

By using the Convert() and the conversion option 108 it is expecting a full date.

Kind Regards,